# It's possible to list subscribers in autobahn.ws?

Tags: websocket, autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar, autobahnws

Currently I'm developing consoles in my webapp displaying user's running *nix application log (game servers) and I just want to make sure that one user can't access other user console by guessing topic name.

I'm using random generated string of 16 chars 0-9, A-Z, a-z, changing on every refresh of page, valid for 30min for each topic name.

Every user of webapp in crossbar config have access to subscribe any topic.
I wanted to set for each user to only subscribe to his/hers console topic but I think that dynamic config for crossbar is not yet implemented.

Is this implementation is enough for privacy of users or it's possible for subscriber to list other subscibers and my work with unique topic names is pointless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible for subscribers to list other subscribers - via [subscription meta-procedures](http://crossbar.io/docs/Subscription-Meta-Events-and-Procedures/).

Regarding your topic structure - you're doing something like

- `com.myapp.userlog.user34KUIK567878`
- `com.myapp.userlog.userAHH78738J899`

and want to prevent users from being able to subscribe to any channel but their own?

For this you can use a dynamic authorizer - see http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/

The dynamic authorizer is called on each subscription (& publish, call, register) request and can then accept or reject this request. It has access to the session data so that you can identify the user.